# How can I copy HTML textbox values from one domain to another domain's textboxes?

Tags: c#, javascript, c++, xss

I'm trying to help save time at work with for a lot of tedious copy/paste tasks we have.

So, we have a propitiatory CRM (with proper HTML ID's, etc for accessing elements) and I'd like to copy those vales from the CRM to textboxes on other web pages (outside of the CRM, so sites like Twitter, Facebook, Google, etc)

I'm aware browsers limit this for security and I'm open to anything, it can be a C#/C++ application, Adobe AIR, etc. We only use Firefox at work so even an extension would work. (We do have GreaseMonkey installed so if that's usable too, sweet).

So, any ideas on how to copy values from one web page to another? Ideally, I'm looking to click a button and have it auto-populate fields. If that button has to launch the web pages that need to be copied over to, that's fine.

Example: Copy customers Username from our CRM, paste it in Facebook's Username field when creating a new account.

UPDATE: To answer a user below, the HTML elements on each domain have specific HTML ID's. The data won't need to be manipulated or cleaned up, just a simple copy from ourCRM.com to facebook.com / twitter.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SO we thought of an easier way to do this (in case anyone else runs into this issue).

1) From our CRM, we added a "Sign up for Facebook" button

2) The button opens a new window with GET variables in the URL

3) Use a greasemonkey script to read those GET variables and fill in textbox values

4) SUCCESS!

Simple, took about 10 minutes to get working. Thanks for you suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

[Ruby Mechanize](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/GUIDE_rdoc.html) is a good bet for scraping the data. Then you can store it and post it however you please.

Answer (score 0):

First, I'd suggest that you more clearly define exactly what it is you're looking to do. I read this as you're trying to take some unstructured data from Point A and copy it to Point B. Do the names of these fields remain constant every time you do the operation? Do you need to simply pull any textbox elements from the page and copy them all over? Do some sort of filtering of this data before writing it over?

Once you've got a clear idea of the requirements, if you go the C# route, I'd use something like [SimpleBrowser](https://github.com/axefrog/SimpleBrowser). Judging by the example on their Github page, you could give it the URL of the page you're looking to copy, then name each of the fields you're looking to obtain the value of, perhaps store these in an IDictionary, then open a new URL and copy those values back into the page (and submit the form).

Alternatively, if you don't know the names of the fields, perhaps there's a provided function in that or a similar project that will allow you to simply enumerate all the text fields on the page and retrieve the values for all of them. Then you'd simply apply some logic of your own to filter those options down to whatever is on the destination form.